# Visual Basic If Then error

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a VB project that I am attempting to use some VBA code that locates duplicate rows based on the first column of an excel sheet, and creates a flag of "1", however the VBA code when used in VB gives the error:

*InvalidCastException was unhandled
Overload resolution failed because no Public '<>' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Operator <>(a As String, b As String) As Boolean':
        Argument matching parameter 'a' cannot convert from '__ComObject' to 'String'.*

```
Public Sub btnRun_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook1 As Excel.Workbook ' Interactions
    Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim MainSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
    xlWorkBook1 = xlWorkBooks.Open(File1_name)
    xlApp.Visible = False

    MainSheet1 = xlWorkBook1.Sheets(1)
    MainSheet1.Activate()

    Dim InteractionRows As Long = MainSheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Total number of rows in the Interaction worksheet
    Dim Duplicate_Found_Index As Long ' Stores all match index values for duplicate interactions
    Dim Duplicate_ID As Long ' Defining the first column to loop through and match duplicate interactions

    ' **** Duplicate Interaction ****
    ' Flag Creation
    For Duplicate_ID = 1 To (InteractionRows)
        If MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 1) <> "" Then 'checking if the cell is having any item, skipping if it is blank.
            Duplicate_Found_Index = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Match(MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 1), MainSheet1.Range("A1:A" & InteractionRows), 0) 'getting match index number for the value of the cell.
            If Duplicate_ID <> Duplicate_Found_Index Then 'if the match index is not equals to current row number, then it is a duplicate value
                MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 34) = "1" ' Print the flag "1" in the 34th column if duplicate found
            Else
                MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 34) = "0" ' Print the flag "0" in the 34th column if no duplicate
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciating in understanding why this error is occuring

Comment: At which line the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Switch Option Strict On if you haven't done so already

Answer (score 2):

The call MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 1) gives Nothing (null) when cell is blank. So instead of matching it with a string, check it for null value.

```
If MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 1) IsNot Nothing Then

End If
```

Comment: Cheers,I have tried the IsNot suggestion. Looks goo so far, however I will do more testing then compare to the IsNot Nothing.

Comment: I have a similar bit of code, which looks for duplicates based on multiple columns. Bit more complex and throwing a different error. I am going to post that too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`IsNot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx) instead for `<>`

```
            If Duplicate_ID IsNot Duplicate_Found_Index Then 'if the match index is not equals to current row number, then it is a duplicate value
                MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 34) = "1" 
            Else
                MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 34) = "0" 
            End If
```

Comment: Except I think the `<>` operator to which the interpreter was objecting is not this one, but rather the one comparing `MainSheet1.Cells(Duplicate_ID, 1)` to the empty string.  It wasn't having a problem with Long values, but with Strings.

Comment: This is incorrect `Duplicate_ID` is a `Long` (value type) so `<>` is the correct operator. `IsNot` is suitable for reference types

Comment: so should it be <> Nothing  ?

Comment: actually. I have tested this using the "IsNot Nothing" and it works fine. The Duplicates are flagged, and the program runs successfully.

Comment: Actually, in attempting to fix other issues, I have turned Option Strict On, and now the same code is throwing COMException was unhandled